# Setting date class to multiple data frame columns whose names are specified in a list

Tags: r, lubridate

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't find an answer.

I wish to only convert specified variables to dates - in reality (not this example) there are many columns to convert to date class. I have specified those columns in a list that I've created manually as below. I'd then like to be able to set date class for just those columns.

Data:

```
library(lubridate)

date1 <- c("19/06/2012", "19/10/2012", "12/08/2012")
var1 <- c("harry", "sally", "dick")
date2 <- c("08/06/2012", "07/11/2012", "19/07/2012")
var2 <- c("london", "paris", "madrid")
date3 <- c("17/07/2012", "18/09/2012", "19/11/2012")

df <- data.frame(date1, var1, date2, var2, date3)

datecols <- list("df$date1", "df$date2", "df$date3")
```

This is where I think I'm going wrong, I make a function to set the dates:

```
setdates <- function(a) {
  a <- a %>%
    dmy(a)
}
```

...but neither lapply:

```
lapply(datecols, setdates)
```

...nor a for loop works

```
for (i in datecols) {
  setdates(i)
}
```

To which I get parsing errors.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find an answer and I think I'm making this harder than it need be.

Comment: Remove the quotation marks from list("df$date1", "df$date2", "df$date3")

Comment: There are a number of things that prevent this to work as expected: 1° putting `"df$date1"` etc in strings. It is possible to make it work, but it's a little more advanced, and probably bad practice anyway. 2° your use of the pipe in `a %>% dmy(a)`: it is superfluous. See `help("%>%")`. 3° Naming your function `setsomething` when it doesn't actually set anything: R doesn't modify function arguments by reference.

Comment: The only errors preventing the OP's code from working are the inappropriate quotation marks.  The other issues are more stylistic.

Comment: Well, yes, I have to agree. I interpreted "style" as expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `dplyr`, you could:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("date")), dmy)

#        date1  var1      date2   var2      date3
# 1 2012-06-19 harry 2012-06-08 london 2012-07-17
# 2 2012-10-19 sally 2012-11-07  paris 2012-09-18
# 3 2012-08-12  dick 2012-07-19 madrid 2012-11-19
```

What it does is: apply `dmy` to those columns in `df` that `starts_with` `"date"`.

Comment: adapting the above, how could you adapt to look for the variable name in the list? Would you use %in%?

Comment: Typing your column names by hand is a risk of bug. It's better to select them programmatically. But if that's what you want/need, you could: `datecols_2 <- c("date1", "date2", "date3") ; mutate_at(df, datecols_2, dmy)`